# Failed to create adjacency list via one array of singly linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, singly-linked-list, adjacency-list

I am trying to create **adjacency list** via one array of singly linked list.

see my code.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdlib>

 using namespace std;

 typedef struct city
 {
      int id;
      struct city *next;
 }city;

 int main()
 {
     int num_city, index = 0, length;
     cin >> num_city;   

     length = num_city;

     city **adj_list = new city*[num_city]; // here it's the header node
     for(int index = 0 ; index < length ; index++)
             adj_list[index] = new city;
     city **temp = adj_list;

     while( num_city -- )
     {
             int a,b;
             cin >> a;
             cin >> b;

             a--;
             b--;       

             city *t1 = new city;
             t1 -> id = a;
             t1 -> next = NULL;

             city *t2 = new city;
             t2 -> id = b;
             t2 -> next = NULL;

             temp[a] -> next = t2;
             temp[b] -> next = t1;  

             temp[a] = temp[a] -> next;
             temp[b] = temp[b] -> next;
      } 
      for ( int index = 0; index < length ; index ++)
             delete []  adj_list[index];
      delete [] adj_list;

    adj_list = NULL;
    exit(0);
  }
```

while I am trying to travel the singly linked list one by one, its output is `NULL`.

After `GDB` this code, and I find that: starting loop, the `city` was created successfully, and `adj_list[index]` could also point the right memory place. Once stepped into the next loop, `adj_list[index]` equals to `NULL` unexpectedly.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems. You are using `temp` to keep track of the last item in of each of the lists. But `temp` points to the original `adj_list` (it *is* `adj_list` rather then being a copy if it), So the result is that `adj_list` itself only keeps the last item you added in each list. If you make a copy of the initial `adj_list` into `temp`, then updating `temp` won't affect the existing items in `adj_list`.

The second problem is that there could be more pairs of neighbours than there are cities. An example for 5 cities: (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,1), (1,5), (4,5), (3,4). So you can't loop on `num_city`. Instead keep looping until user enters `-1` for a city.

I added a constructor `city( int id, city* next )` to make it easier to initialise each new city. `temp` is renamed to `tail` to make it clearer what its purpose is. The function is split into 3 parts, build, print and delete.

```
typedef struct city
{
    int id;
    struct city *next;
    city(int id, city *next) { this->id = id; this->next = next; }
} city;

// pass `adj_list` in as a reference (city **&) so you keep the changes to it when you return
int adj_list_build(city **& adj_list)
{
    int num_city, index = 0;
    cin >> num_city;

    // you need to keep track of the "tail" (end) of each list so you know where to add next item
    city **tail = new city*[num_city];

    adj_list = new city*[num_city];
    for (int index = 0; index < num_city; index++)
    {
        adj_list[index] = new city( index, NULL );
        tail[index] = adj_list[index]; // the tail starts off pointing to the first item in each list
    }

    while (true)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a;               // enter `-1` to stop
        if (a == -1 ) break;
        cin >> b;

        a--;                    // convert to 0-index
        b--;

        city *t1 = new city( a, NULL );
        city *t2 = new city( b, NULL );

        tail[a]->next = t2;
        tail[b]->next = t1;

        tail[a] = t2; // or `tail[a] = tail[a]->next;` - they have same effect 
        tail[b] = t1;
    }
    return num_city;
}

void adj_list_print(city ** adj_list, int length)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        cout << index << ": ";
        city * item = adj_list[index];
        while (item)
        {
            cout << item->id << " " << item->next << " ";
            item = item->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void adj_list_delete(city ** adj_list, int length)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        delete[]  adj_list[index];
    delete[] adj_list;

    adj_list = NULL;
}

void main()
{
    city ** adj_list;
    int len = adj_list_build( adj_list );
    adj_list_print(adj_list, len);
    adj_list_delete(adj_list, len);
}
```